# Why backslash before asterisk in `find`?

Tags: bash, find

In this command:

```
find . -name \*.pyc -delete
```

Why is a backslash needed before `*.pyc` ?

Comment: The man page for `find` should have a section called `NON-BUGS` with something similar as an example and an explanation of why it is needed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

An unquoted glob would be expanded by the shell before `find` is executed.  (Refer to [Filename Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html#Filename-Expansion) in the manual.)

So saying:

```
find . -name *.pyc -delete
```

would actually execute:

```
find . -name file1.pyc file2.pyc file3.pyc -delete
```

assuming there were 3 .pyc files in the current directory and result in an error instead.

A backslash makes the shell pass the glob to `find`, i.e. it acts as if `*.pyc` were quoted.

Ideally, you should be quoting a glob:

```
find . -name '*.pyc' -delete
```

Comment: @RamRachum, but more character when typing.

Comment: @PaulDraper Readable and less prone to mistakes > Shorter by one keystroke

Comment: Single quotes are the way to go. I never even thought you could use the backslash in this way...

Answer (score 5):

Before your shell issues the `find` command, it will do various [expansions](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html). Doing so, it also processes special characters (or, characters with special meaning), where `*` is a wildcard – a globbing character. This is the so-called filename expansion.

Say you have two files in your directory:

- `foo.pyc`
- `bar.pyc`

Then `*.pyc` would expand to both names. So if you write:

```
find . -name *.pyc -delete
```

then the shell will actually call:

```
find . -name foo.pyc bar.pyc -delete
```

which does not make a lot of sense, because you can only have one argument for `-name`. That's why you need to escape the special character to prevent it from being interpreted by the shell. You do that by backslash-escaping, or alternatively, quoting it.